# Can not get bulk manager data from Microsoft graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I want to get all user's and their corresponding manager data from the organization.
In Microsoft Graph explorer I do this:

```
request: GET V1.0
url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=displayName,manager
privileges: I select all existing privileges from the list.
```

Data for the manager is not coming. But I can see the data for "displayName".

For each user when I separately do a request like this:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{...user id...}/manager
```

then I can get the manager data, but I can not get it bulk from the /users?$select endpoint. The organization has 1200 users And I don't want to make 1200 requests to Graph API to get the manager data for each user, instead I want to get the manager data in one request (bulk).

Can please someone help me with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this :

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<user obj id>?$expand=manager
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: This is not answer the question - still need to make 1.2k unique requests to obtain all users manager.